# CloudFormation - Create SNS subscription in disabled state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

Is there a way to create an SNS subscription in the disabled state? This is for a lambda if that makes a difference.

Example:

```
MySubscription:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
  Properties:
    Endpoint: arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:mylambda
    Protocol: lambda
    TopicArn: arn:aws:sns:region:account-id:topic
    Enabled: false # like this
```

Couldn't find anything like this in the AWS CloudFormation documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way with Cloudformation which conforms to your example. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html), `AWS::SNS::Subscription` does not have 'Enabled' as a setting.

Although, the documentation does state that the owner of the endpoint must confirm the subscription before Amazon SNS creates the subscription. So, in a sense, it's already disabled because it doesn't exist until you confirm it on the SNS topic.

Comment: Lambda subscriptions do not need to be confirmed. You could create the subscription without giving SNS permission to invoke the Lambda, but that isn't necessarily what is wanted here.

Comment: I needed to prevent a lambda from receiving messages from a subscription, but keep the subscription, to test an alarm. Mangling the SNS permissions (add some bogus characters to the SourceArn in the Policy) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a condition on the subscription creation.

First add a parameter:

```
   "CreateSubscription": {
      "Type": "String",
      "AllowedValues": [
        "true",
        "false"
      ],
      "Description": "Create subscription to sns"
    }
```

after the 'parameters' section, create a 'conditions' section:

```
"Conditions" : {
    "CreateSubscription" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "CreateSubscription"}, "true"]}
  }
```

add the condition to your subscription

```
"Subscription": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
      "Condition" : "CreateSubscription",
      [...]
}
```

when you want to "activate" you subscription, you just have to change the parameter value updating the stack using the same template

[Conditions section reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html)